# Convexity of help function of a convex multidimensional function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^N \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex.
How can I show that $g_{x,y}: [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, g_{xy}(t):= f((1-t)x+ty)$ is convex, too? $(x,y)$ should be fixed in $g_{x,y}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your notation. When you write $g_{xy}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, are you saying $(x,y)$ is fixed so the question is really convexity for each $(x,y)$ pair? Or are you asking about global convexity for every $(x,y,t)$?

Comment: Sorry, yes $(x,y)$ should be fixed, so that only $t$ varies between $[0,1]$. I edited it. I have tried to show that $g_{x,y}((1-\lambda)t_1+\lambda t_2) \leq (1-\lambda)g(t_1)+ \lambda g(t_2)$ to no conclusion.

Comment: This is exactly the definition of convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go straightforward. For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in[0,1]$,
\begin{align}
g_{xy}\big((1-t)a+tb\big)&=f\Big(\big[1-\big((1-t)a+tb\big)\big]x+\big((1-t)a+tb\big)y\Big)\\&=f\Big((1-t)\big((1-a)x+ay\big)+t\big((1-b)x+by\big)\Big)\\&\leqslant(1-t)f\big((1-a)x+ay\big)+tf\big((1-b)x+by\big)\\&=(1-t)g_{xy}(a)+tg_{xy}(b).
\end{align}